# Java log4j No appenders could be found for logger

Tags: java, log4j

I am trying to make a custom logger and appender in log4j, but I am geting confusing error messages.

Here's the error:

```
[n.a.:n.a.] 19.Apr.2016 15:54      81 [              preRegister] ERROR stderr           - log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (datenImportLogger).
[n.a.:n.a.] 19.Apr.2016 15:54      81 [              preRegister] ERROR stderr           - log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
[n.a.:n.a.] 19.Apr.2016 15:54      81 [              preRegister] ERROR stderr           - log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Here's my config:

```
# datenImportLogger
log4j.logger.datenImportLogger=datenImportFileAppender
log4j.additivity.datenImportLogger=false
log4j.appender.datenImportFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.datenImportFileAppender.File=java/log/datenimport.log
log4j.appender.datenImportFileAppender.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.datenImportFileAppender.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.datenImportFileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.datenImportFileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%X{USER_CODE}:%X{CALLER_ID}] %d{dd.MMM.yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} - %m%n
```

Have I missed something?

Are there any debug Abilities which provide debug on runtime,

because -Dlog4j.debug is not posible.

Logger should be called in code like :

```
private static final Logger     logger      = Logger.getLogger("datenImportLogger");
```

Root Logger is already configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line 
**log4j.logger.datenImportLogger=datenImportFileAppender** is problematic, it miss the level definition

The logger definition should be:

```
log4j.logger.loggerName=[level|INHERITED|NULL], [appenderName1, appenderName2,...]
```

source: [The Complete Log4j Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2970036908)

e.g.

```
log4j.logger.datenImportLogger=INFO, datenImportFileAppender
```

try placing log4j.debug=true in top of the log4.propeties file it should provide additional logging information (although it will have affect only after the configurations are parsed )